# Login as different user while opening site in SharePoint designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I have opened one site in SharePoint designer (SPD) 2013 and used some login.

Now I want to open the same site with different login name but don't see any way.

I tried to google and found article which says

> 1. Open your site in SharePoint designer (designer 2010/ 2013)
> 2. Bottom of the task in SPD, you will find this small icon – please refer the following screenshot.

But I don't see any icon. Here is [link](http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2014/03/sign-in-as-different-user-in-sharepoint.html#.VkwwdXYvdaQ) I was referring too.

I also tried to clear cache and try to open site but it doesnt ask me anything.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SharePoint Designer, select the File tab and navigate to Account > Switch Account (link).

[image]

When there, you can either sign out or switch to another account.

## Force Login on SharePoint Designer

Now, this is a little trickier. You have to add your site as a restricted site in Internet Explorer Options to force SharePoint Designer to ask for credentials. You add your (root) site collection as a restricted site on the security tab:

[image]

Source: [Sharepoint Designer - Change login credentials question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/47453851-3acf-40e2-b848-4afb57645746/sharepoint-designer-change-login-credentials-question)

Comment: i wish to login as domain\username..

Comment: Also by the way i wish to open site using different username and not SPD.. when i opened site for first time in SPD it asked for username and password.. now its not asking

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion See my updated answer how to force SPD to ask for credentials.

Comment: This is awesome. Many thanks thats what i was looking

Comment: You saved my day !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The article referenced in your inquiry may not be clear. To address this issue, I recommend the following steps:

- Click Right on Sharepoint Designer and select Run as a different user,

[image]

**If you couldn't find this option**

- Select open file location > Press Shift and Righ click > Select Run as a different user.

> You can also check another method from this ref : [Sign in as Different User in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/open-sharepoint-designer-as-different-user/)